# Angular UpgradeComponent cannot find $scope

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-upgrade

I have a hybrid angular-cli that roughly follows Victor Savkin's [Lazy Loaded AngularJS guide](https://blog.nrwl.io/using-ngupgrade-like-a-pro-lazy-loading-angularjs-applications-469819f5c86). AngularJS is bootstraped in the constructor of a LazyLoaded Angular module. The main difference between my app and the guide is that I am trying to wrap the `<ui-view>` directive inside of some Angular components. Because of how my layout is structured the `<ui-view>` element will not be available when AngularJS is bootstrapped and may be added or removed at any time.

```
import { Component, Directive, ElementRef, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { UpgradeComponent } from '@angular/upgrade/static';
import * as angular from 'angular';

@Component({
  template: `
  <layout-wrapper>
    <my-toolbar></my-toolbar>
    <layout-contents>
      <ng2-ui-view>
        <h3 class="text-center">AngularJS page not loaded</h3>
      </ng2-ui-view>
    </layout-contents>
  </layout-wrapper>
  `,
})
export class LegacyOutputComponent { }

@Directive({selector: 'ng2-ui-view'})
export class UpgradedUiViewComponent extends UpgradeComponent {
  constructor(ref: ElementRef, inj: Injector) {
    super('uiViewWrapper', ref, inj);
  }
}

export const routerPatchModule = 'arcs.router.patch';

// We need to define a wrapper for ui-view because we can only upgrade
// components with only one definition. uiView cannot be automatically
// upgraded because its definition is too complex
angular.module(routerPatchModule, ['ui.router'])
.component('uiViewWrapper', { template: '<ui-view></ui-view>'})
```

When I run the code a `Error: No provider for $scope!` error is thrown. Checking the stack trace I can see that it is thrown in the `UpgradeComponent` super class. The injector tries to get `$scope` and

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This setup will not work. AngularJS needs to be able to load in the root of your application in order for the scope to be defined correctly.

A better way to approach this problem is to use the `<div ui-view>` directive in the root of your application (as in the upgrade guide) and then to downgrade a layout component from Angular into AngularJS to wrap your content.

Comment: Vizjerai's suggestion still applies to resolve runtime 'NullInjectorError: No provider for $scope!' browser error.

Answer (score 5):

Alternative is to let Angular know that it needs to provide the `$scope`.

```js
import { Injector } from '@angular/core';

// allow $scope to be provided to ng1
export const ScopeProvider = {
  deps: ['$injector'],
  provide: '$scope',
  useFactory: (injector: Injector) => injector.get('$rootScope').$new(),
};
```

```js
@Directive({
  providers: [ ScopeProvider ],
  selector: 'ng2-ui-view',
})
export class UpgradedUiViewComponent extends UpgradeComponent {
  constructor(ref: ElementRef, inj: Injector) {
    super('uiViewWrapper', ref, inj);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks V, that helped me out :+1