# Is there a standard way to get AngularJS to detect the initial values of an UpgradeComponent when it is loaded dynamically?

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap, ng-upgrade, angular-upgrade, ngx-bootstrap-modal

**Background info:**
There is a fairly common problem that was previously brought up in [this github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/27432) about an injector error when using `UpgradeComponent`s inside of dynamically loaded entry components. I feel that I understand this well enough, and have been able to get the scope injected properly by using a similar solution to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50608853/5335355):

```
export const ScopeProvider = {
  deps: ['$injector'],
  provide: '$scope',
  useFactory: scopeFunction,
};

export function scopeFunction(i: any) {
  const newScope = i.get('$rootScope').$new();

  // special property to differentiate this scope from the one coming
  // from the injector that is not used for dynamically loaded components
  newScope.dynamicScope = true;

  return newScope;
}
```

I definitely would like to know if there are pitfalls to this solution that I'm not aware of, as opposed to [the injector solution](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/27432#issuecomment-443994673) mentioned in the github issue.

**However**, that is not my main concern. My main concern is that even with the correct `Injector` and `Scope`, the `UpgradeComponent` still has an issue where the **initial** values on the component are not being detected by angularjs, because there is no `$digest` happening after the component gets created. It's possible that this is specifically a problem with the component loader in `ngx-bootstrap`, and not a general problem with angular, but I'm not sure at this point. The fix I came up with for now is to call `Scope.$evalAsync()` at the end of the constructor for the `UpgradeComponent`, but I'm not sure if this is the right way to go, which is why I am asking this question.

This is an example of the logic for my fix:

```
export class Testng1ComponentFacade extends UpgradeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(elementRef: ElementRef, injector: Injector) {
    super(testng1Component.selector, elementRef, injector);

    const injectorScope = injector.get('$scope');
    if(injectorScope.dynamicScope) {
      console.log('calling $evalAsync() for UpgradeComponent');
      injectorScope.$evalAsync(() => {});
    }
  }

}
```

I kinda based it off of [this angular code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/8.2.14/packages/upgrade/src/common/src/downgrade_component.ts#L184-L186).

**TL;DR:**
Here's a [simple repro](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngupgrade-testing-dynamic-loaded-upgradecomponent) of the issue as well, with my fix included.